# loop based on stored start and end dates in arrays VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Source sheet:
Design: A
data 1
data 2
data 3
data 4
Total for Design A

Design: B
data 5
data 6
data 7
Total for Design B

Info arrangement in the new sheet with a new heading:
data 1        Design A
data 2        Design A
data 3        Design A
data 4        Design A
data 5        Design B
data 6        Design B
data 7        Design B
Total for Design A
Total for Design B

1) How do I loop to collect the Design descriptions in one array and the Total for Designs in another array? Do I need to assign array 0 and 1 for these two arrays?

2) and then do array count to paste them according to the new sheet format?

Is it possible?

Comment: Hi @regina, please could you clarify what `StartCount` and `EndCount` are meant to do?  Are these meant to store the start/end row for lots of different ranges, if so then why are they defined to start from 1 and run until some defined point?

Comment: Hi @Texas - the link on your profile appears to be broken.

Comment: To add to @Texas's comment - are you able to give examples of input data, current output, and *desired* output?  Your current question is very ambiguous.

Comment: Hi Texas, I was also trying to understand that loop why it starts from 1 (this was the existing code that I am trying to change) but I guess it repeats the copying until the last defined point. Yes, it is supposed to store different ranges of start/end rows.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim StRows As Variant
    Dim EndRows As Variant

    Dim aStRow As Variant
    Dim aEndRow As Variant

    StRows = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    EndRows = Array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

    For Each aStRow In StRows
        For Each aEndRow In EndRows
            Debug.Print aStRow & " - " & aEndRow
        Next aEndRow
    Next aStRow

End Sub
```

This will print to individual lines in the `Immediate` window:
`1 - 6, 1 - 7, 1 - 8, 1 - 9, 1 - 10` & then `2 - 6, 2 - 7, 2 - 8....`

Each `StRow` is attached to each `aEndRow`.

Comment: The question is currently quite ambiguous - it could also be requesting an output of `1 - 6, 2 - 7, 3 - 8, 4 - 9, 5 - 10` instead

Answer (score 0):

If start and end have the same number of elements, you can use the same loop/same control variable for both.

```
Sub LoopRanges()

    Dim aStart As Variant
    Dim aEnd As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rCell As Range

    'Start and End have some number of elements
    aStart = Array("A1", "B3", "C10", "D1")
    aEnd = Array("A10", "B15", "C12", "D20")

    With Sheet1
        'loop through start, but use the same control variable (i) for both start and end
        For i = LBound(aStart) To UBound(aStart)
            For Each rCell In .Range(.Range(aStart(i)), .Range(aEnd(i))).Cells
                Debug.Print rCell.Address
            Next rCell
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

This probably ins't your exact situation, but hopefully it's close enough to be instructive. I have two arrays - one for which cell to start in and one for which cell to end in. In my For Next loop, use use `i` as the control variable and access both `aStart` and `aEnd` using that variable. The inner loop is merely building the range for a For Each to iterate through.